# What's the difference between accessing and searching? (when determining time complexity of an array)

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

According to this website: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ Accessing an array is constant time but searching it is O(n). What's the difference between accessing an array and searching it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accesing means looking up an item value by index, while searching means looking up an index by item value. Obviously an array lookup is constant, while linear searching is, well.. linear.

Comment: As an aside, I disagree with what your list says about radix sort. The number of digits has a constant, static ceiling in computing making its performance linear.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing means using the value `a[i]`.  Searching means finding the `i` you want.

For example, where in this answer is the last letter E?  You have to look at every letter in my answer, because I might have written EEEEEEE